# Java code works on my laptop, but not on my desktop?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, file-io

I use IntelliJ. I have a class that manages student grades. It can edit files, which I have a new .temp file being written, and renamed. Then the old file gets deleted. On my laptop (mac) this works fine, but on my desktop (windows) everything works, but the old file is not deleted, and temp is not renamed.

Below is my method to edit the files:

```
private static void editStuGrade() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Enter a course grade you want to change (q1,q2,q3,mid,final): ");
    String editInput = command.next();

    System.out.println("Enter a new score: ");
    String newGrade = command.next();

    Path p = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir"),"src","Assignment1", student.name + ".txt");
    File inputFile = new File(p.toString());
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

    File outputFile = new File(p + ".temp");
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
    OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream);
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(outputStreamWriter);

        if (editInput.equalsIgnoreCase("q1")) {
            writer.write(student.name + "," +  student.id + "," + newGrade + "," + student.quiz2
                    + "," + student.quiz3 + "," + student.midterm + "," + student.finalTest);
            writer.close();
        } else if (editInput.equalsIgnoreCase("q2")) {
            writer.write(student.name + "," +  student.id + "," + student.quiz1 + "," + newGrade
                    + "," + student.quiz3 + "," + student.midterm + "," + student.finalTest);
            writer.close();
        } else if (editInput.equalsIgnoreCase("q3")) {
            writer.write(student.name + "," +  student.id + "," + student.quiz1 + "," + student.quiz2
                    + "," + newGrade + "," + student.midterm + "," + student.finalTest);
            writer.close();
        } else if (editInput.equalsIgnoreCase("mid")) {
            writer.write(student.name + "," +  student.id + "," + student.quiz1 + "," + student.quiz2
                    + "," + student.quiz3 + "," + newGrade + "," + student.finalTest);
            writer.close();
        } else if (editInput.equalsIgnoreCase("final")) {
            writer.write(student.name + "," +  student.id + "," + student.quiz1 + "," + student.quiz2
                    + "," + student.quiz3 + "," + student.midterm + "," + newGrade);
            writer.close();
        }
    inputFile.delete();
    outputFile.renameTo(new File(p.toString()));
    System.out.println("Successful.");
}
```

Comment: Is there any error printing on the console? it's most likely permission issues.

Comment: Try closing your reader.

Comment: @CarloR you mean this? Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:55867', transport: 'socket'

Comment: @tristan I don't think that's it. that doesn't look like an error reading/writing files would throw.

Comment: In fact `inputStream`, `inputStreamReader` and `reader` are all unused. (The difference in behaviour is due to a difference in the behaviour of Windows vs OS X file systems)

Comment: You aren’t seeing what’s actually going wrong, because you are using the very old java.io.File class, many of whose methods hide errors. You should be using the Path class instead. In fact, you already are—you just need to remove the code that converts that Path to a File. Use the [Files](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html) class instead of using FileInputStream and FileOutputStream; for example `Files.newBufferedWriter`, `Files.delete`, `Files.move`. You should not import or use java.io.File at all.  And as others said, close your Writer.

Answer (score 2):

Windows is a special snowflake. Unlike other OSes (or rather, Windows File System, unlike other file systems) does not let you delete any open files, and does not let you rename or delete directories of they contain any open files. In contrast to other OSes which don't mind at all; files on disk are merely 'pointers', and any process that opens a file also gets a pointer. The file isn't truly removed from disk until all pointers are gone, so, you can just delete files - if that file is still open, no problem - as long as it is the file doesn't disappear. It's very similar to java garbage collection in that way.

But not so on windows.

Your code has a bug in it - you aren't managing your resources. This is resulting in the files being open, and then you try to delete them - this works on non-windows filesystems but isn't allowed on windows - you can't delete files even if you're the very process that still has them open.

Resources **MUST** be closed, and the responsibility to do this lies on you. Given that code can exit in many ways (not just 'by running to the end of a method', but also: With `return`, by throwing an exception, by using `break` or `continue` for flow control, etc). Therefore, trying to write code by hand that ensures your resource is closed for all possible exit paths is annoying and error prone, so, don't. Use java's language features:

**Do not EVER open a resource unless you do so in a try-with block**.

Looks like this:

```
try (var outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile)) {
  // outputStream exists here and can be interacted with as normal
}
```

No matter how code flow 'exits' that `try` block, the resource is closed automatically once it does. This is good - not just because this lets you delete those files, but also because every process gets a limited number of files they get to open, so if you fail to close, any non-trivial app will soon hard-crash due to having too many open files.

What are resources? The javadoc will tell you, and use common sense. most InputStream and OutputStreams are - any type that implements AutoClosable tends to be. If you `new X()` them up you definitely have to close them. If you're invoking a method that sounds like it 'makes' the resource (example: `socket.getInputStream` or `Files.newInputStream`), you have to close them.

Use `try () {}` to do this.

Once you do so, you can delete these files just fine, even on windows.